# Hibernate with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have well working Spring Security app which is using Oracle DB. And now I'm having 2 tables (according to [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/) tutorial): `users` and `user_roles`.

```
SQL> DESCRIBE user_roles;

 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 USER_ROLE_ID                              NOT NULL NUMBER
 USERNAME                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
 ROLE                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)

SQL> DESCRIBE users;

 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 USERNAME                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
 PASSWORD                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
 ENABLED                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(1)
```

As you can see there is no `ID` field in `users` table. Two tables binded with `username`. 
Also Hibernate entity requires field with `@Id` annotation. And now the main question:

Is it ok to mark not integer variable as an `@Id`?

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private int enabled;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Comment: Yes sure, you can use it with primitive or wrapper types.

Comment: Let me pick your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, yes it is possible.

More importantly the tutorial you are using is rather bad (having attempted it myself a few times long time ago) in comparison to others available.

A good code example that you will learn a lot from (as did I) can be found here:

http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-security-mysql-hibernate/